# Can I access current report element from conditional style expression?

Tags: jasper-reports

Can I create conditional style based on text value?

For example:

```
<style name="Data">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[!String.valueOf(<CURRENT_DATA>).equals("SOME_VALUE")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style isBold="true" forecolor="#0000FF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Can I access current report element in expressions at all?

I want to do something like that, using conditionalStyle

```
<textField>
    <textElement markup="styled"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[<EXRESSION> == "SOME_VALUE" ? "<style isBold='true'>" + <EXRESSION> + "</style>" : <EXRESSION>]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Update: I looked into source **JRFillTextField.java:488**

```
 protected void evaluateText(byte evaluation)
    throws JRException
  {
    evaluateProperties(evaluation);
    evaluateStyle(evaluation);

    value = evaluateExpression(getExpression(), evaluation);
```

Sad, style evaluated before expression

Comment: `Can I access current report element in expressions at all?` - What do you mean? It seems to me that you do not understand the concept of working *JasperReports*

Comment: Text printed in textField element can be result of some expression like "$F{field1} + $F{field2}"
I need to create style based on expression result. Like set bold if result more then some value for numbers